# Provoke File.mkdirs() to return false in Linux

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I need `mkdirs` to return false in a specific test unit, and since I cannot mock `File` class in Java using Mockito 1 (prior to version 2.0) using JUnit, I used a trick which is to use a valid path name, but with inexistent drive letter (P: for example) under Windows.

Unfortunatly, this trick didn't work with Linux, as I need to throw an Exception (that's what the test unit is intended to do).

How I can obtain `false` when calling `mkdirs`?

Comment: I believe you can use insufficient disk space on a certain drive to simulate this, but a more important question is: do you really need mkdirs to return false?

Comment: Yes, I need false. Otherwise, I would have to change the business logic, which is not the intend of TU.

Comment: why not a path in linux where you don't have permission to write to disk?( I hope  have not misunderstood the question)

Comment: calling `File.mkdirs()` on an existing file will return false.

Comment: I solved the problem using @Riz: `new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/..");`